# Application Error in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I created sample rails app and deployed into heroku. Rails version is 3.1.3 Ruby version 1.8.7-p352, Ruby gem version 1.8.21.

After pushing Rails to Heroku, when I click heroku URL, the below error message in webpage is shown.

> Application Error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page
> could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

i checked my logs in terminal that shows error as follows:

```
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-04-05T05:08:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-04-05T05:08:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-04-05T05:08:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-04-05T05:19:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-04-05T05:19:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-04-05T05:20:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 13221 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:71:in `rescue in establish_connection': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (RuntimeError)
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in `establish_connection'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/rub
y/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:2190:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/product.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load_missing_constant'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `each'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:123:in `constantize'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124:in `block in constantize'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:43:in `constantize'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:128:in `inherited'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:167:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:148:in `_default_wrap_model'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   f
rom /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `depend_on'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23:in `eval'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `new'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:120:in `map'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `block in <main>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:175:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:65:in `start'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.6/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-04-05T05:20:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-04-05T05:20:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-04-05T05:20:08+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I am using MySQL database. Can I run rails app with Mysql database? How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku provides PostgreSQL out of the box hence the errors about the `pg` gem.  You've two options.

1. Either tweak your application to use PostgreSQL, which shouldn't be that hard if you're using an ORM such as ActiveRecord and assuming that you're using no custom SQL, or
2. Flip to using one of the MySQL add-ons such as [ClearDB](https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb) or [Amazon RDS](https://addons.heroku.com/amazon_rds).

Comment: How do you "tweak your application" to use postgresql? just add the gem for postgresql to production in gemfile?

Comment: Pretty much - Flip to the `pg` gem and the rest should be done by Heroku if you're using the Heroku provisioned DB

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the postures gem in your gemfile

```
gem "pg"
```

is what you need

Comment: i am using mysql database then why i put pg gem

Comment: Heroku provides PostGres database by default - you would need to use a mySQL addon if you want to use mySQL on Heroku or use your own.

Comment: there is no MySQL add-on in heroku.how to get MySQL add-on?

Comment: I think there might be a mysql add on but you have to pay.extra for it. Check the addons page on the Heroku management web page.  All instructions for using it will be there. But unless you **really** need mysql the Heroku postgres offering is very very good.